# Problem with firebase(web) database/storage rules and authentication

Tags: javascript, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-authentication

I have a web app(**upload.html**) to upload files and data on firebase. I need to login (on **index.html**)  to access  **upload.html** .I can upload file to firebase on test mode but when I apply rules I can't upload file even if I'm authenticated (logged in).
My goal is to allow only authenticated users to write data.

**upload.js**

```
//redirect to login page if user is not logged in
firebase.auth().onAuthStateChanged((user) => {
  if(!user){
    location.replace('./index.html');
  }
});
```

**Firebase Rules:**

**Storage:**

```
rules_version = '2';
service firebase.storage {
  match /b/{bucket}/o {
    match /{allPaths=**} {
      allow read;
      allow write: if request.auth != null; //this line is making problem 
    }
  }
}
```

**Database:**

```
{
  "rules": {
    ".read": true,
    ".write": "auth != null" //problem on this line
  }
}
```

Comment: Can you share your complete `upload.html` file?

Comment: It's just a form link to upload.js

Comment: It still might be useful to understand what might be causing the issue.

Comment: https://pastebin.com/9SEKmcSU